# C easy program not working - "if"

Tags: c, if-statement

I tried to write an easy program that compares 3 numbers and prints the biggest of them but it keeps printing all 3 of them and I don't get why. That's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int x = 10;
  int y = 8;
  int z = 3;

  if((x > y) && (x > z));
  {
    printf("%d",x);
  }

  if((y > x) && (y > z));
  {
    printf("%d",y);
  }
  if((z > x) && (z > y));
  {
    printf("%d",z);
  }
  return 0;

}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Do not put semicolons at the end of `if` statements.

Comment: You have semi-colons at the end of your `if` statements.  So you are saying `if (something) empty_statement`, and then your `printf` blocks are unqualified by any `if` test.  IOW, they will execute every time because there is no conditional test associated with them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the semicolon at the end of each if statement.   That is causing the if statement to run the null statement (;) and then subsequently run a block statement { printf(...); }

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

  int x = 10;
  int y = 8;
  int z = 3;


  if((x > y) && (x > z))
  {
    printf("%d",x);
  }

  if((y > x) && (y > z))
  {
    printf("%d",y);
  }
  if((z > x) && (z > y))
  {
    printf("%d",z);
  }
  return 0;

}
```

Comment: Oh, I should ve known that myself.. but thanks for the fast answer!

Answer (score 3):

You should use else , you should remove the semi-colons after the if statements , the semi colons after ifs means that the body of the if is empty and the other stuff is a normal block of code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

  int x = 10;
  int y = 8;
  int z = 3;


  if((x > y) && (x > z))
  {
   printf("%d",x);
  }
  else { // Will not make difference in this particular case as your conditions cannot overlap
  if((y > x) && (y > z))
  {
    printf("%d",y);
  }

  else { // Will not make difference in this particular case as your conditions cannot overlap

  if((z > x) && (z > y))
      {
    printf("%d",z);
      }
  }
}
  return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have a semicolon after your `if` condition:

```
if((x > y) && (x > z));
```

The semicolon takes the place of the block or statement to be executed when the condition is true.  It's as if you had written:

```
if((x > y) && (x > z))
  {
    ;
  }
  {
    printf("%d",x);
  }
```

You can hopefully see how this will execute the print statement unconditionally.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is purely based on the knowledge of using semicolon in C and syntax of `if` statement.

For more information read [semicolon](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?SemiColon) and have a clear understanding of`if`[syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fh88ctk1.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The logic is simplier if you use an additional variable for maximum

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int x,y,z, max;
    scanf ("%d", &x);
    max = x;
    scanf ("%d", &y);
    if (y > max)
        max = y;
    scanf ("%d", &z);
    if (z > max)
        max = z;

    printf ("max = %d", max);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your answer doesn't explain why OP's `if` statements were ignored.

Comment: And what is more, it shows that there are other ways to think. Unthinkable!

Comment: The scanf is no needed here but thanks for your nice suggestion with the maxiumum variable. :)